# font size and width control of datepickerrange

Tags: plotly-dash

how to make start date and end date appear at one line for datepickerrange component.

for example, mine is the first figure, but i want it look like 2nd figure.

here is my code:

```
html.H4('Select a start and end date:'),
dcc.DatePickerRange(id='date-range',
                   min_date_allowed=datetime(2020,1,1),
                   max_date_allowed=datetime.today(),
                   start_date=start_date, 
                   end_date=end_date,
                   style = {
                        'font-size': '6px','display': 'inline-block', 'border-radius' : '2px', 
                        'border' : '1px solid #ccc', 'color': '#333', 
                        'border-spacing' : '0', 'border-collapse' :'separate'
                        } 
                   )
```

in CSS file, i also added this and it doesn't work, Thanks for help, please

```
.DateInput, .DateInput_1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I added your code to a html.Div

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime 


app = dash.Dash(__name__, meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width"}])


app.layout = html.Div([html.H4('Select a start and end date:'),
                    dcc.DatePickerRange(id='date-range',
                   min_date_allowed=datetime(2020,1,1),
                   max_date_allowed=datetime.today(),
                   start_date=datetime(2020,1,1), 
                   end_date=datetime(2020,1,1),
                   style = {
                        'font-size': '6px','display': 'inline-block', 'border-radius' : '2px', 
                        'border' : '1px solid #ccc', 'color': '#333', 
                        'border-spacing' : '0', 'border-collapse' :'separate'
                        } )
                 ])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

And I got it

Comment: Thanks Youssef, it didn't work either, for my same code, if I ran it in my home desktop, it is fine. if I run it in my work pc, it is not working, any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Please check your Virtual Environment. I think this video may help 


https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z58KGp1t4Qw

Enjoy